# javascript or php monitoring file content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file

I have a log file.

I would like to show on a web page it's content and all the changes that happen on it.

Like a monitoring file content.

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That should be easy. Poll the server via Ajax and return the file contents. Please clarify what you have tried so far and/or where you have problems solving it on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its incrementally increasing file (new content only appends to the end of the previous content), I'd store somewhere the last known size of that file, and when next access, I'd read this possition and read the file from this position to the end. Something like

```
$last_known_size = 1024; // I set this to some value, read it from your location as mentioned at the end of this example.

$filename = 'thelogfile.log';
$handle = $fopen($filename, 'r');

fseek($handle, $last_known_size);
$new_log_size = filesize($filename);
$new_log_content = fread($handle, $new_log_size);

fclose($handle);
```

and store the value of $new_log_size anywhere as you need (memory, filesystem, database ...) for your next read ...

Answer (score 1):

In order to to that you need to save the timestamp or date/time when you add a line to the log. Then you can use file_get_contents("dir/file.txt") to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of useful links:

Intervals: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Reading files: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ or http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reading2.htm

You could also use php to read the file instead of javascript using ajax.